# DoubleLinkList Append Value

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list

I have a question: How the first Node in my double link list get the value? Could someone explain it? Because what i see in append_value function is to add the end Node value not the first Node value. But when i try to run the code, the first Node somehow has some value. thanks.

Please see the code:

```
struct Node
 {
 int value;
 Node *next;
 Node *prev;
 };

class DoubleLinkList
{
    private:
        Node *first;
        Node *end;
    public:
        DoubleLinkList();
        void show_list();
        void append_value(int);
};

DoubleLinkList::DoubleLinkList()
{
 first = NULL;
 end = NULL;
} 

void DoubleLinkList::show_list()
{
 Node *node;
 node = first;
    while(node)
    {
    cout << node->value << " ";
    node = node->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void DoubleLinkList::append_value(int value)
{
 Node *ptr = end;
 end = new Node;
if (first == NULL)
 first = end;
else
 ptr->next = end;
if(end)
 {
   end->next = NULL;
   end->prev = ptr;
   end->value = value;
 }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand.  You wrote the code and don't know how it works?

Comment: The function `append_value` will add a new node, which contains a value, to the end of the list. If the list was empty, then adding a new node to the end of the list will effectively also add that node to the start of the list.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem (including any necessary inputs, but preferably not needing any), then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Comment: @Popolocrois Did the answers help?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, in a doubly linked list, when the head pointer is nul, this indicates that the list is empty:

```
void DoubleLinkList::append_value(int value)
{
//...
    if (first == nullptr)
    {
       // List is empty
    }
//...
}
```

At this time, the head pointer and the end pointer are set to the new node, thus placing a node into the list:

```
//...
    if (first == nullptr)
    {
        first = end;  
    }
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify it by filling in the `Node` values on construction:

```
void DoubleLinkList::append_value(int value) {
    end = new Node{value, nullptr, end};

    // Check if there was a node there since before and, if so, make it point
    // at the new `end`.

    if(end->prev) {
        end->prev->next = end;
    } else {
        first = end; // this is the first node added, make it point at `end`
    }
}
```

Note: You also need a destructor to `delete` the objects and implement/`delete` the copy constructor, copy assignment operator, move constructor and move assignment operator.

See [The rule of five](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)